# Extract frequency of appeared values in R

Tags: r, count

I have a table as follow:

```
dt<-data.frame(Date=c(1,1,2,2,3),Zone1=c(NA,5,6,7,NA),Zone2=c(NA,5,6,7,NA),Zone3=c(NA,6,NA,NA,NA))
  Date Zone1 Zone2 Zone3
1    1    NA    NA    NA
2    1     5     5     6
3    2     6     6    NA
4    2     7     7    NA
5    3    NA    NA    NA
```

I want to know the frequency of appeared numbers (5,6,7) and correspdonding date like this:

```
 Date "5" "6" "7"
    1  2  1  0
    2  0  2  2
    3  0  0  0
```

Can you suggest me a fastest way to have the output like that?

Comment: I corrected my output. Your code is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`, we can `gather` the data into long format, `count` `Date` and `Zone` columns and `spread` the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  gather(key, value, -Date, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  count(Date, value) %>%
  spread(value, n, fill = 0)

#   Date   `5`   `6`   `7`
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     1     0
#2     2     0     2     2
```

Comment: If I add 3rd day with only NA values. The 3rd day will not show up in output. How can I  keep the date, even if value is NA. Please see my example

Comment: @JennyPham In that case, you can do `dt %>%
  gather(key, value, -Date) %>%
  mutate(Date = factor(Date, levels = unique(Date))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  count(Date, value, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  spread(value, n, fill = 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(dt), id.var = 'Date'), Date ~ value, 
    length, drop = FALSE)[, .(Date, `5`, `6`, `7`)]
#   Date 5 6 7
#1:    1 2 1 0
#2:    2 0 2 2
#3:    3 0 0 0
```

---

Or with `base R` using `table`

```
table(dt$Date[col(dt[-1])], unlist(dt[-1]), useNA = 'always')
```